# Все файлы на удаленном репозиторие обновляются, а сам сайт нет

Tags: git, bitbucket, repository

Дело в том, что я делал уже где то 10 `push` и все работало. И по этой схеме я делал каждий раз почти.

В этот раз, перед тем как сделать `push origin` я сделал `merge`, сделал `pull`. Git сам попросил сделать `pull`. Потом все мои изменения я запушил.

Захожу на репозиторий, смотрю все файлы обновились, `master` тоже. Открываю сайт, но все без изменений. Подождал 30 мин, час(может надо было время обработать). Было где то 10 коммтов). Но все тщетно. 
Может проблемы с `cache-ом`?

Comment: Это все зависит от того, как у вас сайт связан с репозиторием.

Comment: @insolor Дело в том, что я делал уже где то 10 `push`. В каком смысле связан с репозиторием?

Comment: Почему вы решили, что push должен каким-то образом менять сайт?

Comment: Подсказка кроется в deploy :-) Посмотрите предлагаемые способы и настройте :-)

Comment: Ну, `git push origin master` отправляет все измененные файлы на `origin` ветку `master`.  Я на данный момент не спец в `git-e`, но работать могу. 
И зачем задавать еще вопрос, если я попросил помощь?) @andreymal

Comment: Блин, я немного прочитал про `deploy, prodaction`и что то связанное с ним, это что то запредельное для меня сейчас). Можно какую то ссылку для новичка  @Nilsan

Comment: Почему вы решили, что origin ветка master должна каким-то образом менять сайт?

Comment: @МишаПодлевских, объясните что такое "все работало". И поймите, что бы объяснить "для новичка" нужно понимать что вы уже знаете. Это было бы проще, если бы вы подробней описали что у вас уже есть. В целом система система управления версиями не предназначена, напрямую, для изменения работы сайтов.

Comment: @МишаПодлевских _Блин, я немного прочитал про deploy, prodaction_ - а нужно прочитать много и самое главное понять логику того как это устроено и работает. По другому нормального результата не будет